# Adding alert condition to script

Tags: alert, pine-script

The crossing zero (0) condition exists but I want to add the condition marking the peak of both the crest and the trough. In other words, where the bars turn either maroon (dark red) or dark green.

This is another user's public code and I think this would be valuable for all of us using tradingview.

```
length = input(20, title="BB Length")
mult = input(2.0,title="BB MultFactor")
lengthKC=input(20, title="KC Length")
multKC = input(1.5, title="KC MultFactor")

useTrueRange = input(true, title="Use TrueRange (KC)", type=bool)

// Calculate BB
source = close
basis = sma(source, length)
dev = multKC * stdev(source, length)
upperBB = basis + dev
lowerBB = basis - dev

// Calculate KC
ma = sma(source, lengthKC)
range = useTrueRange ? tr : (high - low)
rangema = sma(range, lengthKC)
upperKC = ma + rangema * multKC
lowerKC = ma - rangema * multKC

sqzOn  = (lowerBB > lowerKC) and (upperBB < upperKC)
sqzOff = (lowerBB < lowerKC) and (upperBB > upperKC)
noSqz  = (sqzOn == false) and (sqzOff == false)

val = linreg(source  -  avg(avg(highest(high, lengthKC), lowest(low, 
lengthKC)),sma(close,lengthKC)), lengthKC,0)

bcolor = iff( val > 0, 
        iff( val > nz(val[1]), lime, green),
        iff( val < nz(val[1]), red, maroon))
scolor = noSqz ? blue : sqzOn ? black : gray 
plot(val, color=bcolor, style=histogram, linewidth=4)
plot(0, color=scolor, style=cross, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this at the end:

```
peak = bcolor == green and bcolor[1] == lime
trough = bcolor == maroon and bcolor[1] == red
bgcolor(color = peak ? lime : trough ? red : na)
alertcondition(peak, "Peak", "Peak")
alertcondition(trough, "Trough", "Trough")
```

Comment: holy cow, that higlighted the actual peak and trough. Is there anyway you can create the alert  condition for it?

If you can do this, I'd be willing to share a very lucrative strategy with you (by the way).

Also, THANK YOU. That is amazing so far.

Comment: I tried giving your post an UP rating but it says I don't have the rating.

Comment: See edit to code. Thx for the offer but I'm all set with strats.

Comment: Yeah, ah, of course, after your work, I was able to create the alerts and you confirmed that it. THANK YOU! Would you be interested in a monetary compensation? I'd post my e-mail so that you can e-mail me and I can do an e-transfer to express my gratitude. You should accept. 

Thanks again. I am very grateful for your input. Also, if I can do anything for you otherwise, just say. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy you're happy. Just accept the answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting arrows.